# count empty cells until the next filled cell

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a table similar to the one below and like to automate the calculation of the sum column. The number of rows per day varies. I'm looking for a way to find the number of empty cells in the date column after the current row. This number can then be used to fill the sum column.

Is there regardless of the solution below a way to count the number of empty cells between the dates?

```
Date      |Value|Sum
----------+-----+---
16/07/2020|    2|  5
          |    3|
17/07/2020|    2| 10
          |    3|
          |    5|
18/07/2020|    2| 11
          |    3|
          |    5|
          |    1|
```

Answer (score 2):

if you start from row 1 use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A="",,VLOOKUP(A:A, QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A), 
 FILTER({ROW(A:A), A:A}, A:A<>""), 2), B:B},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A:A, QUERY(IF(B:B="",,VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A), 
 IF(A:A<>"", {ROW(A:A), A:A}), 2, 1)),
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there regardless of this solution a way to count the number of empty cells between the dates?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, but why does the column "B" matter in this second formula?

Comment: it matters because otherwise you would get count for all the rows spreadsheet has. see F1 and notice F19 - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zsdge_Sv66o7yhLpKJqD25u0JDsocVd4-7ZZhNKCqOE/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the answer to your first  question to figure out the answer to the Sum.

With the entirety of column C blank, try this in C1:

=ARRAYFORMULA({"Sum";IF(A2:A="",,VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER({ROW(A2:A),A2:A},A2:A<>""),2),B2:B},"Select Col1,SUM(Col2) group by Col1"),2,0))})

If that doesn't work, it might be easier to demonstrate the idea on a sample sheet.

Comment: Matt, funny: you posted as I was posting, and our ideas were exactly the same.

Comment: @ErikTyler That'll happen :)

Answer (score 1):

André, try this:

1.) Delete C:C entirely (including the header).

2.) Place the following formula into cell C1:

```
=ArrayFormula({"Sum";IF(A2:A="","",VLOOKUP(A2:A,QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A),FILTER({ROW(A2:A),A2:A},A2:A<>"",B2:B<>""),2,TRUE),B2:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) Group By Col1"),2,FALSE))})
```

**UPDATE:**

Your post example shows headers. The formula I suggested, then, accounted for those headers. Since your actual sample sheet is different and *does not use headers like the original post*, you'd use this version:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="","",VLOOKUP(A:A,QUERY({VLOOKUP(ROW(A:A),FILTER({ROW(A:A),A:A},A:A<>"",B:B<>""),2,TRUE),B:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) Group By Col1"),2,FALSE)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work and results in an error while parsing the formula. I created a simple example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zsdge_Sv66o7yhLpKJqD25u0JDsocVd4-7ZZhNKCqOE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The formula I provided (and the one Matt provided) assumed that your data column had a header, which is standard. It doesn't. I edited my post to show the version without a header, which works fine.

Comment: My real problem has a header and is much more complicated. I simplified the question and the example sheet.

Comment: The only problem for Matt and me was that the example in the post (with headers) didn't match the sheet (without headers). That is why the original formulas wouldn't have worked: because they were written for headers. But at the end of the day, you got it solved. That's the main goal.